# Drupal menu calling variables in the template

Tags: forms

When I use these functions it gives me a permanent redirect error on the code whereas when I use other page callback it does not give me any problems.

```
    function kbc_menu() {

     $items['hello3'] = array(
     'title' =>'Hello World!',
      'page callback' =>'mypage',  
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

    );
    }

function mypage() {
   $asdas ="asdasd";
  return theme('my_custom_template', array('out'=>$asdas));
}

function kbc_theme() {
  return array(
      'my_custom_template' => array(
        'template' => 'view-location',

      ),      
   );
}
```